# Configuring WebClient with keyStore and ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction - troubleshooting SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, spring-boot, webclient

I am trying to call a customer's endpoint to retrieve their data using `WebClient`. We have to use certificate when calling the endpoint. I configured the `WebClient` with filter (to handle auto-refresh of the access token) and also with httpclient taking the certificate as keyStore. However, I am getting the `SSLHandshakeException`. If I commented out the filter(oauth), then I didn't get the SSLHandshakeException. Can someone please let me know how to let `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` work with the keyStore setup? Thanks.

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    private final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebClientConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private DVSVerifySslContextBuilder sslContextbuilder;

    @Autowired
    private SslDetailsLoader sslDetailsLoader;

    @Autowired
    private CertificateConverter certificateConverter;

    @Value("${service.cert.keystorePassword}")
    private String keystorePassword;

    @Value("${service.cert.privateKeyPassword}")
    private String privateKeyPassword;

    @Value("${okapi.sslConfigName}")
    private String sslConfigName;
    
    @Value("${dvs.verify.base.uri}")
    private String baseUri;

    @Bean
    public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository getRegistration(

            @Value("${dvs.verify.accessTokenUri}") final String accessTokenUri,
            @Value("${dvs.verify.client-id}") final String clientId,
            @Value("${dvs.verify.client-secret}") final String clientSecret,
            @Value("${dvs.verify.grant-type}") final String grantType,
            @Value("${dvs.verify.scope}") final String scope) {
        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("dvs").tokenUri(accessTokenUri)
                .clientId(clientId).scope(scope).clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS).build();
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {
        var clientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrations);
        var authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrations, clientService);
        var oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("dvs");

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
                .secure(sslSpec -> sslSpec.sslContext(getKeyStorefromMassl(sslConfigName)))
                .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000)
                .doOnConnected(
                          connection -> {
                            connection.addHandlerLast(
                                new ReadTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                            connection.addHandlerLast(
                                new WriteTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                          });
        return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).filter(oauth).baseUrl(baseUri)
                .filter(errorHandler()).build();
    }

    private ExchangeFilterFunction errorHandler() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
            if (clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError() || clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError())
                return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .flatMap(errorBody -> Mono.error(new IllegalAccessException(errorBody)));
            else
                return Mono.just(clientResponse);
        });
    }

    private SslContext getKeyStorefromMassl(String sslConfigName) {
        SslContext sslcontext = null;
        try {
            // setting passwords for keystore load
            sslContextbuilder.setSslDetailsLoader(sslDetailsLoader);
            sslContextbuilder.setPrivateKeyPassword(privateKeyPassword.toCharArray());
            sslContextbuilder.setCertificateConverter(certificateConverter);
            SslDetails sslDetails = sslDetailsLoader.loadOkapiCerts(sslConfigName);
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            trustStore.load(null, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
            logger.info("I have build the keystore for the trust manager.");
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            keyStore.load(null, keystorePassword.toCharArray());
            logger.info("I have build the keystore for the key manager.");
            certificateConverter.loadCertificateAuthorities(sslDetails, trustStore);
            /*
             * Load the my public certificate and key into the key store.
             */
            certificateConverter.loadCertificateAndKey(sslDetails, keyStore, privateKeyPassword.toCharArray());
            sslcontext = sslContextbuilder.buildInternallySslContext(sslDetails, trustStore, keyStore, sslConfigName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed getKeyStorefromMassl ==>", e.getMessage());
        }
        return sslcontext;
    }
}
```

And calling post method from service class

```
ResponseEntity<IdvResponse> response = webClient.post().uri(baseUriVerifyExt).headers(getDefaultHttpHeaders())
                    .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId("dvs"))
                    .body(Mono.just(idvRequest), IdvRequest.class).retrieve().toEntity(IdvResponse.class).block();
```

Can someone please let me know how to let `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` work with the `keyStore` setup? Thanks.